# After Java update to the version 1.8.0_301 JavaFX WebView with Leaflet.Draw.Circle, Leaflet.Edit.Circle does not work as well as OSM is not draggable

Tags: javascript, java, webview, leaflet

I am using JavaFX Webview with Leaflet library  to render OSM tiles. I am running into issues with Circles and Polygons, Marker and with some functions as Editting, Removing, Zoom.
All these Leaflet-functions are working fine under the old java versions as jdk1.8.0_191, jdk1.8.0_241.
But after the update java to the version jdk1.8.0_311 it is not possible to draw Circle around a Marker as well as editting a Circle and a Polygon. Furthemore the osm-map is not draggable  on a JXPanel, it looks like the map is fixed to panel.
I am running Windows 10.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks&Regards

Comment: Would be interessting if it works with [Leaflet-Geoman](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman)

Comment: This is already the second problem report related to newer versions of JavaFX and Leaflet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69872483/leaflet-does-not-work-in-webengine-after-javafx-17 Something seems to be going wrong here indeed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @FalkeDesign: I have verified **Leaflet-Geoman** with JavaFX WebView and mouse events as dragging, Edit Circle do not work too. But event Draw Circle works. Is it possible to adapt some Leaflet Codes as Draw.Circle, Edit.Circle, Drag Layer to Java 1.8.0_301?

Comment: Please create a new [Issue on Leeaflet-Geoman](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman/issues) then we can talk about what you need and how we can help. PS: if the answer from @mipa was useful, please upvote or accept it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have entered this into the JDK bug database because there seems to be a more general issue here. See: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8276859  This is also not the only report about such an issue. See also: [Leaflet does not work in WebEngine after JavaFX 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69872483/leaflet-does-not-work-in-webengine-after-javafx-17/69899621#69899621)

**Edit:** The underlying issue has been fixed as of March 1, 2022. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8278759

Comment: @FalkeDesign: Coud you send me a test html-file with leaflet-geoman library as draw.circle, edit.circle? I would like run it under WebView. Thanks.